# How to order by an attribute of a parent for a polymorphic model in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, scope-chain

I think I worded that correctly...

I have a model called asset which is polymorphic:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
...
end
```

I have a class level method that acts as a scope:

```
def self.some_scope
     assets = Asset.joins(:assetable).where('assetable.approved_at IS NOT NULL').order('assetable.approved_at DESC').limit(50)
end
```

I am trying to get a list of assets who's parent's `approved_at` attribute is not null and order by that `approved_at` attribute in descending order with a limit of 50.  I'll admit that I'm not sure how close what I have is to being correct but the error I am getting now is:

```
"Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :assetable"
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to think of it differently like:

```
# If assetable model is called Folder
def self.some_scope
   folders = Folder.where('approved_at IS NOT NULL').order('approved_at DESC').limit(50)
   folders.collect{|p| p.assets}
end
```